# Double chained list problems passing char[] with function

Tags: c

I have been working on a school project that requires working with double-chained list with struct. I have managed to create the functions that add an integer and a char to the struct. But when I attempt to add the char it wont works, but with the integer, works fine.
I'm working with 3 files, the header.h, function.c, and main.c
main.c file:

```
No* primeiro = NULL;
No* atual = NULL;

int i, val;
char tecla;
char nome[50];

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("Digite o valor: ");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    getchar();
    printf("\nType something: ");
    fgets(nome, 50, stdin);
    inserir_final(&primeiro, val, nome);
}
```

The function file:

```
struct no{
  int elemento;
  char nome[50];

  struct no *anterior;
  struct no *proximo;
};

void inserir_final (No **primeiro, int valor,  char nome[]){
  No* novo = novo_no(valor, nome);
  No* aux;

  if(*primeiro == NULL){
    *primeiro = novo;
  }
  else
  {
    novo->proximo = *primeiro;
    (*primeiro)->anterior->proximo = novo;
    novo->anterior=(*primeiro)->anterior;
    (*primeiro)->anterior = novo;
  }
  }

No* novo_no(int dado,  char nome[]){
  No* aux = (No*)malloc(sizeof(No));

  aux->elemento = dado;
  strcpy(aux->nome, nome);

  aux->proximo = aux;
  aux->anterior = aux;
  return aux;
    }
```

This is how I print it:

```
void listar_nos(No* primeiro){
No* aux = primeiro;

printf("Listagem do primeiro ao ultimo: \n");
if (primeiro == NULL)
    return;

do
{
    printf("Elemento: %d\n", aux->elemento);
    printf("Nome: %s\n", aux->nome);
    aux = aux->proximo;
} while (aux != primeiro);

printf("\n\nListagem do ultimo ao primeiro: \n");

aux = aux->anterior;

do
{
    printf("Elemento: %d\n", aux->elemento);
    aux=aux->anterior;
} while (aux->proximo!=primeiro); 
}
```

The output:

```
Digite o valor: 10

Type something: ola
Digite o valor: 20

Type something: ok
Digite o valor: 30

Type something: po


 Digite p para proximo e A para anteriro:s

 Todos os nos: Listagem do primeiro ao ultimo:
 Elemento: 10
 Nome: ñ
 Elemento: 20
 Nome: ▄
 Elemento: 30
 Nome: $
```

Comment: So how does it fail?  What do you see when it doesn't work?

Comment: I get number, for example the output from the  char are numbers

Comment: I have updated with the output

Comment: It may be a problem with the code that reports the data.  You should post that, too.

Comment: I have updated with the print form

Comment: Am I inserting the string right?

Comment: Fix the output and we will find out!

Comment: Didn't wok, updated question with the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is passed to a function as a pointer.  You are printing the numerical value of the pointer.  To print the string, you want to use `%s`, not `%d`.